# How to open a vagrant file in notepad on windows

Tags: powershell, window, vagrant, config

This will download a “Vagrant” file, which you need to open with notepad
and add the following line: “config.VM.provision: reload“. It should
resemble the following when completed:`enter code here`

```
         Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| 
         config.vm.provision :reload 
          config.vm.synced_folder
```

I am so confused on the open with notepad part help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open notepad, you can just use PowerShell to add the text. If you have the file on disk something like this should work:

```
$StringToAdd = 'config.VM.provision: reload'
$VagrantFilePath = 'C:\path\Vagrantfile'
$StringToAdd | Add-Content $VagrantFilePath
```